# Resizing TextView to fit text (with a nine patch background image)?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, android-adapter, nine-patch

I am using a TextView and a 9 patch image as its background for a messaging application in android.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

See how for the blue, it is showing too much on the left? How can I reduce it when it decides that it has to wrap the text?

I tried to access the Width and Height fields on the view in `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`, however they are always zero (ps the TextView is located inside of a ListView and the `getView` method is inside the adapter for the ListView).

Thank you!

---

### TextView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_b"
    android:shadowColor="@color/textShadow"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Also, here's a screen of what the nine-patch does for it, so you can see how that works for it:

[image]

Comment: What is difference between gray and blue one? Why does gray one shows it well? Did you try to put padding to `TextView`? Also if they are `9patch` images, I think you left less space in blue one compared to gray one. I would draw my 9 patch again

Comment: I want it to reflect the blue more than the gray. The gray was a different issue that is now fixed. I'll reupload the photo. I want the bubble to hug the text more tightly. I think it has something to do with the textview sizing more so than the nine patch.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I mean whatever you did to gray do same to the blue. When you draw 9patch, leave more space on left and right.9 patch only stretches the area in the middle.

Comment: My 9patch both the padding and the patch, are tight because I want the bubble to tightly wrap the text, similar to what you would find on the iphone message UI (http://www.allgeek.tv/wp-content/uploads/2010/ios5ipad_imessage.png)

Comment: I got it now. Can you post your xml code for TextView?

Comment: Probably you need to set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for the `TextView`

Comment: Sadly, I already tried that... :(

Comment: Problem is not 9patch, I misunderstood your question. Set your `layout_gravity` to `right`. Do this `android:layout_gravity="right"`  because you need to align your `TextView` to right and then wrap content. So it will wrap left side.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32359/discussion-between-robby-cohen-and-gokhan-arik)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the iPad picture you attached, iMessage is setting `maxWidth` to the half of the screen I guess.

So you can get `Screen Width` and set `maxWidth` to half of it for your `TextView`
This is how you can get screen width and pass it to your `TextView`,

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
yourTextView.setMaxWidth(display.getWidth()/2);
```

P.S. `getWidth` method for `Display` class says deprecated, you can find alternative solution to this. You can get `width` of your `LinearLayout` also.

[image: This is how it looks on my device]

Comment: Thanks for all of the help man! I really appreciate it. While this doesn't tightly wrap all of the text, this is the closest I'm gonna get and you took plenty of time to help, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check the 9-patch image in draw9patch. Check how for to the left you draw the black lines in there. I think the bottom line defines what part to stretch, the top line defines the area for the content.

Comment: I think it's the other way around, but thank you for pointing out that the two lines do different things!